# Не работает выполнение команд командной строки после сборки питоновского скрипта в exe нуиткой

Tags: python-3.x, консоль

Приветики!
Написала на 3 питоне скрипт выполняющий в командной строке команду используя -

```
subprocess.Popen('help',stderr=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

после выполнения циклом читается вывод и ошибки командами -

```
out = proc.stdout.readline()
out += proc.stderr.read()
```

Работало все идеально пока не потребовалось собрать скрипт в exe. Собирала нуиткой. Если собирать без опции `--windows-disable-console` скрипт работает так-же безотказно, если же использовать эту опцию (а именно это мне и нужно, ибо к чему черный экран висит и окно лишнее открыто, а без этого процесс сидит себе, в диспетчере задач виден, все оки-доки) то...команды перестают работать, как ни странно, не все, простой `echo` или `chcp 65001` работают, а вот `help` или `dir` ничего не выводят. Подскажите пожалуйста, как две горошки на ложку собрать, и окна чтобы не было и скрипт чтобы  работал?

Comment: 1- попробуйте `stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL`. 2- не имеет отношения к вопросу, но полезно в целом: читайте потоки одновременно иначе в общем случае deadlock можно получить, если системный буфер для соответствующего канала заполнится. В вашем случае, просто объедините каналы: `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` и/или используйте `communicate()`. Или ещё проще: `subprocess.run('dir', shell=True, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, check=True)` (ну и конечно, вместо `dir` вы можете `os.scandir()` или аналог вызывать).